# React Native Expo : facing a problem in passing Value to Other Screnns

Tags: expo, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I am creating a notepad app.
I have three screens : index screen which handles my drawer and stack , AllNotes And EditScreen .
The problem is In Edite screen .I create Text Input and handled it with states but when the user clicks on the add button which is exist editScreen naviagtion I want to add that Note to AllNotes,
How can I pass the Value .plz help I am a beginer

> here is the Edite_Screen in app.js

```
const EditeScreene = ({ navigation , props }) => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="homee"
      component={EditScreen}
      options={{
        title: "Edite Screen",
        headerTitleStyle: {
          textAlign: "center",
        },
        headerLeft: (props) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
            <AntDesign
              name="back"
              size={30}
              color="red"
              style={{ margin: 10 }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerRight: () => (
          <TouchableOpacit onPress={}>
            <MaterialIcons name="done" size={34} color="black" />
          </TouchableOpacit>
        ),
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

> here is my AllNotes_Screen

```
const AllNotes = ({ navigation , props}) => {

  const [NewNotes, setNewNotes] = React.useState([]);
  // handling textinput function
  // handing Updated Notes
  const handleNotes = () => {
    setNewNotes([...NewNotes, props.notes]);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.searchInput}>
        <MaterialIcons
          name="search"
          size={22}
          style={styles.searchIcon}
          color="#bbb"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputText}
          placeholder={"I'm looking for..."}
          placeholderTextColor={"#999"}
          underlineColorAndroid={"#fff"}
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText={AddNotes}
          value={notes}
        />
      </View>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.notesContainer}>

        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.plusContainer}>
        <EvilIcons
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Editee")}
          name="plus"
          size={74}
          color="black"
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

};

> here is my EditeScreen

```
const EditeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  // manges textInput starts
  const [notes, setNotes] = React.useState("");
  //getting text input value
  const HandlingTextValut = (EnteredNotes) => {
    setNotes(EnteredNotes);
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.InputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputText}
          placeholder={"Take Notes ..."}
          onChangeText={HandlingTextValut}
          value={notes}
        />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In a production app, it would be good to use a more durable technique for managing your notes state, like storing it in a `Context`. You could then access that context from both of your screens and dispatch actions to it.

For the code you posted, though, a quicker solution would be to pass the note as a navigation param when you switch screens. You can then access the passed data from the `navigation` prop and do whatever you want with it. If you look through the documentation for the `navigate` method in the library, you can find more information on this.

Comment: Can you please give an example in my code